# Filtering on one element in comma delimited field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have the following field in MongoDB:

"wind": "N, NE, E",

How would I go about filtering on just one of the elements in the wind field?

e.g. just "NE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$regex`

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fMKVrAsfxau)

```
db.collection.find({
  "key": {
    $regex: ",\\s*NE\\s*,"
  }
})
```

But if they are separate elements, I suggest you to use an array.